# How to show out more fields of Employee in Odoo 13 Enterprise?

Tags: module, field, odoo

Currently, The employee module just show out with 3 fields: Job title, Work Mobile and Work Email.

[image]

So how to show out more details with more fields of an Employee?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend hr employees kanban view.

You may try following code:

```
<record id="hr_kanban_view_employees" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">hr.employee.kanban</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.hr_kanban_view_employees"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('oe_kanban_details')]" position="inside">
            <field name="passport_id"/>
            <field name="FIELD_NAME"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```